# Jade Angular2 Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: angular, pug, event-binding

templating an angular2 app with jade-lang I'm getting the following error.

"Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

Without the event-bing (click)="..." everything works fine.

```jade
p Some Contacts List Page
  md-nav-list
    a( (click)="gotoContact()" *ngFor="let contact of contacts; let i = index" )
        md-list-item {{i+1}} {{contact.nameFirst}}{{contact.nameFam}}
```

Does someone have a hint how to solve or workaround ?

Here the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tip0e.png)

Answer (score 0):

putting into quotes is a solution:

'(click)'="gotoContact(contact)"

maybe someone gets accross this.